# Angular how to bind service variable in component

Tags: angular

I, am creating a shopping cart with angular but i have a problem i create a cart service.
everything works fines but only one issue is that i create a variable with the name of **finalamount** in this variable i put total amount of cart. when i click on add to cart button the **finalamount** variable showing null. when i refresh page then its shown actual value in component

**cart.service.ts**

```
finalamount = 0.00;
calculatecart() {
this.amount = 0.00;
for (let item of Object.keys(this.finalcartdata)) {
  var items  = this.finalcartdata[item]
  this.amount += parseFloat(items.itemprice) * parseInt(items.itemquantity);

}
this.finalamount = +this.amount + +this.shipping;
```

}

**home.component.ts**

```
cartamount = 0.00;
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private HttpService: HttpService, private CartService: CartService) {
this.cartamount = this.CartService.finalamount;
```

}

i want when i click on add to cart the total catamount automatically update without refresh

Thank You.

Comment: Share some more code, from where you are updating the cart and at what place (storage) you are saving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is not reflecting on-page is the only thing. You have to keep some type of observable(Subject) in your service.

in your service.

```
finalamount$: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

calculatecart() {
this.amount = 0.00;
for (let item of Object.keys(this.finalcartdata)) {
  var items  = this.finalcartdata[item]
  this.amount += parseFloat(items.itemprice) * parseInt(items.itemquantity);

}
this.finalamount$.next(+this.amount + +this.shipping);
```

And in your component subscribe to it.

```
this.CartService.finalamount$.subscribe((amount)=> {
   this.cartamount = amount || 0.00;
})
```

Comment: Its work fine on runtime but when i refresh my page the total amount showing 0.00 
i get data from localstorage and i call in html file variable like this {{finalamount}}

Comment: finalamount$: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
 finalcartdata: any = [];
 cartItemsData:any =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartdata') || '[]');
 constructor() {
    this.finalcartdata = this.cartItemsData;
    this.calculatecart();
    //localStorage.removeItem('cartdata');
  }
  calculatecart() {
    this.amount = 0.00;
    for (let item of Object.keys(this.finalcartdata)) {
      var items  = this.finalcartdata[item]
      this.amount += parseFloat(items.itemprice) * parseInt(items.itemquantity);
    }
    this.finalamount$.next(+this.amount + +this.shipping);
  }